# PHP tracking outgoing link but execlude bots? And a small if statement question

Tags: php, if-statement, preg-match

I'm making a script, where i want track the unique clicks on the outgoing links e.g. "out.php?id=1" (its a php header redirect).

but I don't want track the hits from the spider crawlers? Should i do a simple preg_match('/google|yahoo/') or something ? What would be the best solution?

Than i have a question about a statement i have following data in the table

```
IP - DOMAIN 
127.0.0.1 Google.com
```

Now i want if 127.0.0.1 clicks a link on my page and it dont goes to google.com it should get counted.

than the table would look

```
IP - DOMAIN
127.0.0.1 GOOGLE.com
127.0.0.1 yahoo.com
```

Sorry im thinking all the day about the statement, how to do it, but i don't get it =) sorry I just learned / learning coding.

Comment: Could you clarify the part of the question about the table?

Comment: Well, there is a TABLE counter_in with the rows (timestamp - ip - domain) where the data gets entered. Well i need the php statement how to do it, php should check if the ip exist if its exist it should check if its matches the domain...lol..by typing i think i found it out. will you update :)

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to just add your out.php (or whatever you end up calling the redirect file) to [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard). Otherwise you'll probably have to resort to sniffing `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` as you suggested yourself.

Comment: rel="nofollow" dont passes link juice, but google crawls it. yeah thinking about user_agent too.